# Cant update Firefox on Centos

Tags: firefox, centos

I'm trying to update my version of Firefox on my Centos 6 machine. 
I've downloaded the  tar.bzip2 file from Mozilla website. Unpacked it in the /opt folder. I backed up my old firefox version:

```
mv /usr/bin/firefox /usr/bin/firefox-old
```

and  created a new link for the new version

```
ln -s /opt/firefox45/firefox /usr/bin/firefox
```

When I run the `firefox` command from the terminal and check the version its still on Version 31

When I run `firefox -V` it returns `Mozilla Firefox 45.0.1`

How is this happening and why won't the  browser of 45.0.1 version open?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running

```
# whereis firefox
```

on my CentOS 7 returns:

```
firefox: /usr/bin/firefox /usr/lib64/firefox /usr/share/man/man1/firefox.1.gz
```

The library for Firefox is in /usr/lib64/firefox, so to fix it, I ran:

```
# mv /usr/lib64/firefox /usr/lib64/firefox38
# cp -r /home/derek/Downloads/firefox /usr/lib64/firefox
```

running

```
$ firefox
```

and checking the version gives me v. 45,

```
$ firefox -v
```

returns

```
Mozilla Firefox 45.0.1
```

Hope this helps!

EDIT: Note that the reference given in

```
/home/derek/Downloads/firefox
```

is referencing the unpacked archive downloaded from the Mozilla website. The rest of the commands should be similar.